# Can't jump to the end of a page in Vim 8

Tags: vim

Since I updated to Vim 8 pressing `j` or `L` on the last visible row makes the screen scroll down. I can't have the cursor be on the last row.

I did not have this behaviour with Vim 7.4, so it looks like something changes?

Comment: What on earth are you asking? Rewite your question, as it stands I have no idea what the problem is.

Comment: See `:help defaults.vim`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're experiencing the effects of

```
set scrolloff=5
```

Vim 8.0 introduced more sensible (compared to vi compatibility) defaults when the user does not have his own `~/.vimrc` file.

This is explained at `:help defaults.vim`. If you want your old behavior back, just create an (empty) `~/.vimrc` file. If you like the new defaults (most make a lot of sense), put the following into the file:

```
unlet! skip_defaults_vim
source $VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim

" Undo the new scrolloff setting, I don't like it.
set scrolloff=0
```